uso de zip en python
No entiendo este ejercicio alguien me puede ayudar
Crea el zip con las traducciones los números del 1 al 5 en español, portugués e inglés (en el mismo orden), y convierte el objeto generado en una lista almacenada en la variable numeros:
uno / um / one
dos / dois / two
tres / três / three
cuatro / quatro / four
cinco / cinco / five

El resultado deberá seguir la estructura:
[('uno', 'um', 'one'), ('dos', 'dois', 'two'), ... ]

Hola Alejandro, bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Te has mirado la documentación oficial de la función zip()? La conversion a lista es simplemente numeros = list(zip(iterable1, iterable2, iterable3, ...)) En tu pregunta no queda muy claro de que datos partes ¿tienes una lista para cada uno de los tres idiomas con los numeros? considera aclarar esto, y si te atascas agrega lo que has intentado a la pregunta y aclara de que datos parte el ejercicio para que podamos ayudar.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

zip es un creador de un iterador de tuplas en base a iteradores individuales. De la documentación zip:

zip(*iterables, strict=False)
Iterar sobre varios iterables en paralelo, generando tuplas con un item para cada una.
Más formalmente: zip() retorna un iterador de tuplas, donde la tupla i-ésima contiene el elemento i-ésimo de cada uno de los argumentos iterables.

Puedes almacenar ese iterable en una variable, por ejemplo:
es = ['uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'cuatro', 'cinco']
pt = ['um', 'dois', 'três', 'quatro', 'cinco']
en = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']

numeros = zip(es, pt, en)

for num in numeros:
  print(num)

Te imprimirá
('uno', 'um', 'one')
('dos', 'dois', 'two')
('tres', 'três', 'three')
('cuatro', 'quatro', 'four')
('cinco', 'cinco', 'five')

Finalmente, dado que te piden

El resultado deberá seguir la estructura:
[('uno', 'um', 'one'), ('dos', 'dois', 'two'), ... ]

Eso es una lista, por lo que puedes usar la construcción list(iterador) para convertir el resultado en una lista:
lista = list(zip(es, pt, en))
print(lista)

Imprimirá:
[('uno', 'um', 'one'), ('dos', 'dois', 'two'), ('tres', 'três', 'three'), ('cuatro', 'quatro', 'four'), ('cinco', 'cinco', 'five')]


En vez de publicar tu propia traducción de la documentación en inglés de una versión de hace 10 años, podrías lincar la documentación español de la versión más actualizada: zip.

Hombre, gracias por la recomendación. Suelo llegar a la documentación haciendo búsquedas de Google, y uso lo que tengo a mano mientras escribo la respuesta. En muchos sitios la traducción al español es malísima, así que yo suelo leerla para mi en Inglés y, como cortesía, la traduzco aquí al español. Voy a tener en cuenta tu sugerencia  la próxima vez que escriba una respuesta sobre python. Edité la respuesta para usarla aquí.
